# Terminate method execution from another in PHP

Tags: php, function, oop, terminate

In the basic example below I'm expecting that the one() method terminates the two() method when the if statements returns true, but it always returns 'something'. How can I terminate the execution of method two() from method one()?

```
Class MYclass {

    // This method must ends two()
    private function one($var){
       
       if( $var == 'value' ) {
         return;
       }
    
    }

    public function two(){

       $this->one('value'); // if parameter is 'value' this must ends here 
    
       return 'something'; // else it will return something
    }

}

$three = new Myclass;

echo $three->two(); // This outputs 'something' but I'm expecting nothing
```

Comment: Make method one return a value to indicate what should happen, and have method two check that returned value before deciding what to do next

Comment: Your phrasing is a bit misleading here, _"Terminate method execution"_ makes it sound as if you wanted to interfere with a method that currently _is_ running (like executing a loop with longer runtime), but it appears you actually just want a method to do different things, based on a criterion determined by a different method call.

Comment: Method `two()` will always return `something` because its coded to always return `something` Step 1: bench check you logic, ...... Step 10: come to SO

Answer (score 4):

Let method one() to return really-something (like a boolean true|false) then check what is returned. For example:

```
Class MYclass {

    // This method must ends two()
    private function one($var){
       
       if( $var == 'value' ) {
         return true;
       }
       return false;  // else return false

    }

    public function two(){

       if ($this->one('value')) {
          return ;
       }
       return 'something'; // else it will return something
    }

}
```

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that, in PHP in particular, `return;` is equivalent to `return null;` and so the reason you get no output when you call `echo $three->two();` is that `echo null;` doesn't output anything.

Comment: Ok this was my initial solution, but What if the return of one() Is a real value? Do I have to repeat like this `if ($this->one('value')) {
          return $this->one('value');
       }` it's a Little annoying

Comment: Probably something like this is best one line solution `if( $one = $this->one($request) ) return $one;`

Comment: yup! that was what I wanted to write... (otherwise it will now return always nothing)